# How to recognize the wallpaper groups of these patterns?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetry

[image]

I'm trying to get the wallpaper groups of these pictures. Any body can help me with this? I just can't get all 17 groups. How to identify them?
（BTW just ignore my writings lol! I feel I just made mistakes）

Answer (score 2):

There is a very useful [Patern Recognition Algorithm](http://www.math.toronto.edu/~drorbn/Gallery/Symmetry/Tilings/Sanderson/index.html), which explains exactly how to identify the corresponding wallpaper group.