# Which wallpaper groups do these images belong to?

Tags: group-theory, plane-geometry, symmetry

The three images below are 'pieces' of infinite wallpaper patterns. The first one corresponds to an infinite checkerboard pattern with alternating white and black squares. The second image corresponds to an infinite checkerboard pattern with alternating white, black, and red squares. The third image corresponds to an infinite checkerboard pattern with white, black, green, and red squares. I believe the first image belongs to the wallpaper group p4m, and the third and fourth images belong to wallpaper groups pm. Is this correct? What about the case with C >= 5 colours, constructed in the same way. What is the best classic reference for wallpaper groups? Thank you.

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

[image: Image 3]

Comment: from which book is this taken from ?

Comment: what is a wallpaper group?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallpaper_group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@DietrichBurde has an [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3480999) linking to [Brian Sanderson's Pattern Recognition Algorithm](http://www.math.toronto.edu/%7Edrorbn/Gallery/Symmetry/Tilings/Sanderson/index.html); that page has a further link or two you can follow for more information.

As for good classical references, it's a problem. One of these days I'll turn my Euclidean geometry course into a book, the culmination of which will be the classification of the 17 wallpaper groups.

---

Let me follow that pattern recognition algorithm on your examples.

**Your first example:**

> *What is the maximum rotation order?*

The maximum is $4$, with rotation axis at the center of any black or any white square. Note every other rotation axis is at the common corner of two black and two white squares, or at the midpoint of the common edge of a black and a white square; at each such point, the rotation order is $2$.

> *Is there a mirror?*

Yes, the mirrors are the lines of slope $0$, $1$, $-1$, or $\infty$ that pass through the center of any black or white square.

> *Is there a rotation axis not on a mirror?*

No, every rotation axis is on a mirror.

> *Conclusion:* Your first example is of type p4m, as you surmised.

**Your second and third examples:**

These two are the same:

- The maximum rotation order is $1$;
- There is a mirror, namely any line of slope $-1$ passing through the center of any square.
- There is no indecomposable glide reflection, because in both of your these examples every glide reflection decomposes as one of the mirror reflections composed with a translation along the mirror axis.

So both of these wallpaper groups are of type pm, again as you surmised. The same logic would apply to any number of colors $\ge 3$, they are all of type pm.

Comment: For the colors = 2 case, what is the extended color group called, i.e., when we include both color preserving and color reversing symmetries? And in the colors >= 3 case, what is the extended color group called when we include the 'color-turning' symmetries, i.e. symmetries that cause the colors to cycle?

Comment: Looks to me like the classification of the group is unchanged in both cases: still p4m for the first one; still pm for the second and third.

Comment: E.g., for the color = 2 case, a rotation of 90 degrees around a vertex of a square reverses color! This is not a regular symmetry as all symmetrirs of p4m preserve color.

Comment: That is true. And yet, the two groups are abstractly the same (i.e. they are isomorphic as groups). I suggest you go through that Pattern Recognition Algorithm for yourself to verify this fact. If that's still not convincing enough, then you might wish to delve into the geometry and mathematics which underlie that algorithm.

Comment: The Pattern Recognition Algorithm ignores color. As explained on page 123 of 'Creating Symmetry' by Frank Farris, " .. the set of symmetries and antisymmetries together form one big group, ...".

Comment: The Pattern Recognition Algorithm may be used for any symmetries based on any characteristics, whether they are symmetries based on shape alone, or shape and color, or perhaps some other characteristics. It is our job to apply it correctly to the pattern at hand. If you are unsure of how to apply it, that might be good material for a new question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144828/discussion-between-marcus-and-lee-mosher).