# What exactly is a colour reversing symmetry of a wallpaper pattern?

Tags: finite-groups, plane-geometry, symmetry

Using Brian Sanderson's Pattern Recognition Algorithm ([link](http://www.math.toronto.edu/%7Edrorbn/Gallery/Symmetry/Tilings/Sanderson/index.html)) we readily see that the pattern below corresponds to the Wallpaper Group labelled p4m. This is just an infinite checkerboard of alternating black and white squares. Notice with this pattern that if we rotate the whole checkerboard by 90 degrees around the center of a square the plane is unchanged. Black squares are mapped to black squares and white squares are mapped to white squares. However, if we rotate the whole checkerboard by 90 degrees around the vertex of a square, black squares are mapped to white squares (and vice-versa). Is this a 'colour reversing symmetry'? If so, does it belong to the symmetries of p4m? Or does it belong to some larger group that includes both colour preserving and colour reversing symmetries? (As Frank Farris seems to be suggesting on page 123 of his book 'Creating Symmetry'). Notice however, that black and white squares are also reversed if we shift the whole checkerboard by one square (up/down or left/right), which suggests that the colour reversing symmetry is also a symmetry (because the plane is infinite and so shifts yield the same pattern). Now I'm confused. Can someone help me out? (By the way, I do understand that when defining the symmetry of a coloured wallpaper pattern in addition to having an isometry we also have a function that maps points to colours).

[image]

Comment: You have asked almost the same question [yesterday](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4664114/305862) ; moreover you have had an excellent answer. Re-posting without  mentionning the previous question is **not fair** : people risk to lose their time trying to redo what has been done before. Imagine that all other askers do the same...

Comment: It was suggested by another person when the discussion became somewhat tangential that I ask this question separately. It's not the same question. Here I am asking about colored symmetry, which is not the same thing.

Comment: Nevertheless, you should have mentionned your earlier question (at least for seeing the answer given).

Comment: Jean Marie, I've only used StackExchange a handful of times, so you will excuse me if I'm not familiar with proper etiquette. Nevertheless, your comments, e.g. telling me what I should have done, seem to suggest you are an authority on this site, which I doubt. So maybe in future you can remind people a little more politely if you feel that proper etiquette has not been followed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree  that the term "wallpaper pattern" is usually tossed around without giving a rigorous definition, and this can lead to confusion. One workable definition is that it is a *periodic function defined on the plane*. The function  may be real-valued  if you wish to create gray-scale images or  complex-valued if we wish to include color as Frank Faris does).

The color wheel can be modeled using the complex plane. Each point on the unit circle has a color or complex phase value associated to it, and radial distance inn the plane describes saturation. A colored wallpaper pattern is then a periodic function  $f: {\mathbb R}^2\to {\mathbb C}$.

Within a given fundamental period parallelogram, a colored pattern may have additional color-reversing symmetries (quasi-symmetries). Such quasi-symmetries   are Euclidean motions $g$ for which $ f(g(x)) = m(g) f(x)$ where the complex multiplier  $m(g)$ represents a phase-shift that alters the color. Since iterates of $g$ correspond to repeated alterations of phase, the phase changes must be cyclic. Thus it turns out the multipliers take values on the unit circle $U$ in the complex plane. The group of quasi-symmetries is richer than the collection  of true symmetries. (The true symmetry group is a subgroups of the group of quasi-symmetries.)

P.S. Since $f$ is periodic, it has two linearly independent  fundamental period vectors. Taking $x,y$ to be coefficients of these basis vectors,  we can WLOG assume that the fundamental period parallelogram is the unit square. Then $f$ can be expressed as a complex Fourier series in two variables: $f(x,y) = \sum_{j,k} c_{j,k} e^{ 2\pi i (k x+jy)}$. The frequency lattice $(j,k)$ carries a collection of complex-valued coefficients $c_{j,k}$ that uniquely determine $f$. Thus we can also regard the wallpaper pattern as an assignment of complex numbers on the frequency lattice.  Frank Farris discusses in detail how affine  motions acting in $(x,y)$ space such as $(x,y)\to (x',y')=(ax+by +t,  cx+dy + s)$ manifest themselves as phase-change factors on the frequency lattice. The frequency-plane description sheds extra light on what possible discrete subgroups are possible. In particular one sees easily that e.g translation through a fraction of a full period must correspond to a phase shift through a fraction of the unit circle.